# Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open

Tags: emacs, editor

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269812/how-to-quickly-get-started-at-using-and-learning-emacs), it's trying to find out how to do something like this which should be easy, that especially stops me from getting more used to using Emacs and instead starting up the editor I'm already familiar with. I use the example here fairly often in editing multiple files.

In Ultraedit I'd do Alt+s then p to display a dialog box with the options: Find (includes using regular expressions across multiple lines), Replace with, In Files/Types, Directory, Match Case, Match Whole Word Only, List Changed Files and Search Sub Directories. Usually I'll first use the mouse to click-drag select the text that I want to replace.

Using only Emacs itself (on Windows XP), without calling any external utility, how to replace all foo\nbar with bar\nbaz in `*.c` and `*.h` files in some folder and all folders beneath it. Maybe Emacs is not the best tool to do this with, but how can it be done easily with a minimal command?

Answer (score 407, accepted):

1. `M-x find-name-dired`: you will be prompted for a root directory and a filename pattern.
2. Press `t` to "toggle mark" for all files found.
3. Press `Q` for "Query-Replace in Files...": you will be prompted for query/substitution regexps.
4. Proceed as with `query-replace-regexp`: `SPACE` to replace and move to next match, `n` to skip a match, etc.
5. Press `C-x s` to save buffers. (You can then press `y` for yes, `n` for no, or `!` for yes for all)

Comment: I don't think this is recursive though, no? Otherwise it's a great option for a single directory.

Comment: No, it's recursive. The non-recursive version would be %m in dired-mode.

Comment: On Windows with GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600), after entering the filename pattern it fails with "find exited abnormally with code 1" – Rob Kam (0 secs ago)

Comment: This is probably a problem with the emacs/find configuration, possibly related to http://www.archivum.info/bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org/2005-10/msg00120.html What's the text of the error?

Comment: find . "(" -iname "test.c" ")" -exec ls -ld "{}" ";"
  Access denied - .
  File not found - -INAME
  File not found - TEST.C
  File not found - )
  File not found - -EXEC
  File not found - LS
  File not found - -LD
  File not found - {}
  File not found - ;

Comment: That's almost certainly an Emacs bug.

Comment: Maybe because you're calling C:\WINDOWS\system32\find.exe, not GNU find.

Comment: Yes that's it. It works if I get it to use the find.exe from MSYS instead.

Comment: Any hints on how to save all the marked files in the dired-buffer? BTW, thanks for a clear and precise answer: +1

Comment: Steen, I'd like to know that myself. I always switch to the buffer list and save them there ("s" to mark for saving, "x" to save all marked).

Comment: Steen, Chris: Probably not exactly what you want but you can use 'C-x s' (save-some-buffers), it will prompt you for each modified file, so you only have to hit 'y' multiple times.

Comment: The reason you get "find exited abnormally with code 1" on Windows is that Emacs shells out to the find command. The default find.exe on Windows will not work, since it isn't compatible with Unix find. To fix, install Cygwin or alternative and ensure that the directory containing the Unix version is in front of the Windows version in the PATH.

Comment: Now, I found it. So, the path to cygwin\bin should come first before windows\system32.

Comment: `C-x s !` to save all the files at once.

Comment: `M-,` to continue search and replace (for example after "revert file" prompt if file changed on disk).

Comment: What's the proper find regex for multiple file extensions? Eg using `*(txt|html)` gets converted to `find . \( -iname \*\(coffee\|html\) \) -ls`, which doesn't work. Is there any way to convert to the -o or -regex mentioned here: ? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions

Comment: There is `find-lisp-find-dired` which does not requires GNU find, so it works on all platforms. besides, it supports unicode file name out of the box.

Comment: Someone know a way to use `!` to replace all instances but instead it replace all instances in ALL files?

Comment: Can I combine all these operations as a single key-binding, where inputs is pressed by default after `find-name-dired` . For example, key-binding will do all those at once: find-name-dired) , enter , *py ,t, Q .. and continue from this point

Comment: At step 4 this opens `helm-xref` for me, and it seems to be a prompt I'm meant to type something in. Space just types a literal ` `, where am I going wrong?

Comment: can it be done case sensetive?

Comment: It seems broken. I type the usual `^J^Jpattern` which works in usual regexp-replace, and fails on me with "No matches for" ‍♂️

Answer (score 41):

- `M-x find-name-dired RET`

  - it may take some time for all the files to appear in the list, scroll to bottom (`M->`) until "`find finished`" appears to make sure they all have loaded
- Press `t` to "toggle mark" for all files found
- Press `Q` for "Query-Replace in Files...": you will be prompted for query/substitution regexps.
- Proceed as with query-replace-regexp: SPACE or `y` to replace and move to next match, n to skip a match, etc.

  - Type ! to replace all occurrences in current file without asking, `N` to skip all possible replacement for rest of the current file. (`N` is emacs 23+ only)
  - To do the replacement on all files without further asking, type `Y`.
- Call “ibuffer” (`C-x C-b` if bound to ibuffer, or `M-x ibuffer RET`) to list all opened files.
- Type `* u` to mark all unsaved files, type `S` to save all marked files
- `* * RET` to unmark all marks, or type `D` to close all marked files

This answer is combined from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270930/using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open/271136#271136), from [this site](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/find_replace_inter.html), and from my own notes. Using Emacs 23+.

Comment: `ibuffer` is not bound to `C-x C-b` by default.

Comment: Well personally I recommend that people *do* bind `C-x C-b` to `ibuffer`, because it's so much better than the default binding. Just add `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)` to your .emacs file. Failing that, use `M-x ibuffer RET` in the above instructions.

Comment: ok.  I think I have the emacs startup kit, which is why mine is bound

Comment: File `bla-bla-bla` is visited read-only and it stops to searching. How to avoid / ignore that and keep replacing? Thanks.

Comment: Why `ibuffer` when you can `C-x s` (`save-some-buffers`) and type `!`? I don't want to be rant, just curious. P. S. plus for describing `!`, `N` and `Y`.

Comment: When I try to do `* u` it says `* is undefined`@Frank Henard

Comment: @alper, I'm not certain what's going on for you, but make sure you're using ibuffer

Answer (score 25):

Projectile is really nice: 
C-c p r runs the command projectile-replace

Comment: Can I apply this only for python files?

Comment: Buffers need to be saved after walk throughout all queries.

Answer (score 20):

The answers provided are great, however I thought I'd add a slightly different approach.

It's a more interactive method, and requires `wgrep`, `rgrep` and `iedit`. Both `iedit` and `wgrep` must be installed via MELPA or Marmalade (using `M-x package-list-packages`)

First run `M-x rgrep` to find the string you're looking for.

You'll be able to specify file types/pattern and the folder to recurse.

Next you'll need to run `wgrep` start it with `C-s C-p`.

Wgrep will let you edit the `rgrep` results, so set a region on the string to match and start `iedit-mode` with `C-;` (depending on your terminal you may need to re-bind this)

All occurrences will be editable at once. `C-x C-s` to commit `wgrep`. Then `C-x s !` to save the changed files.

The main benefit of this method is that you can use `iedit-mode` to toggle off certain matches `M-;`. You can also use the results in `rgrep` to jump into the files, for example if you have an unexpected match.

I find it very useful for doing source edits and renaming symbols (variables, function names etc.) across a project.

If you don't already know/use iedit mode it's a very handy tool, I strongly recommend you give it a look.

Comment: This technique is pretty powerful even without using iedit. It turns knowing how to grep (easy with lgrep/rgrep) into knowing how to bulk search-replace!

Comment: Combining rgrep/wgrep/macros is awesome.

Comment: Keybinding to start `wgrep` is `C-c C-p` btw.

Answer (score 13):

I generally use other tools to perform this task, and it seems like many of the approaches mentioned at [EmacsWiki's Find and Replace Across Files entry](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategorySearchAndReplace#toc4) shell out, but the [Findr Package](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindrPackage) looks very promising.

Stealing part of [the source file](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/emacs/findr.el):

```
(defun findr-query-replace (from to name dir)
  "Do `query-replace-regexp' of FROM with TO, on each file found by findr.
```

Comment: how do I try to found string "Collectible" in all file with extension java and hxx using findr.el?

Comment: @swdev: M-x findr-query-replace RET Collectible RET <the replacement> RET .*\.java RET <the directory to start searching in> RET

Comment: I like this approach (it avoids all the toggling involved in the direct approach). I use some convenience functions to combine this with projectile (project-root-discover), and replace the thing at point: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/055a9d62f9fc824153599724b8f44d57

Comment: can I apply this for only python files?

Answer (score 8):

Source of information: [1](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/find_replace_inter.html)

**For emacs pro users:**

1. Call dired to list files in dir, or call find-dired if you need all subdirectories.
2. Mark the files you want. You can mark by regex by typing 【% m】.
3. Type Q to call dired-do-query-replace-regexp.
4. Type your find regex and replace string. 〔☛ common elisp regex pattern〕
5. For each occurrence, type y to replace, n to skip. Type 【Ctrl+g】 to abort the whole operation.
6. Type ! to replace all occurrences in current file without asking, N to skip all possible replacement for rest of the current file. (N is emacs 23 only)
7. To do the replacement on all files without further asking, type Y. (Emacs 23 only)
8. Call ibuffer to list all opened files. Type 【* u】 to mark all unsaved files, type S to save all marked files, type D to close them all.

**Step-by-Step Guide for Emacs Beginners**

Select Target Files

Start emacs by typing “emacs” in the command line interface prompt. (Or, double click the Emacs icon if you are in a Graphics User Interface environment)

Selecting Files in a Directory

First you need to select the files you want to do the replace. Use the graphical menu 〖File ▸ Open Directory〗. Emacs will ask you for a directory path. Type the directory path, then press Enter.

Now, you will be shown the list of files, and now you need to mark the files you want the regex find/replace to work on. You mark a file by moving the cursor to the file you want, then press m. Unmark it by pressing u. (To list subdirectories, move your cursor to the directory and press i. The sub-directory's content will be listed at the bottom.) To mark all files by a regex, type 【% m】, then type your regex pattern. For example, if you want to mark all HTML files, then type 【% m】 then .html$. (You can find a list of the mark commands in the graphical menu “Mark” (this menu appears when you are in the dired mode).)

Selecting Files in a Directory and All Its Sub-Directories

If you want to do find/replace on files inside a directory, including hundreds of subdirectories, here's a method to select all these files.

Call find-dired. (you call a command by pressing 【Alt+x】) Then, type a directory name, ⁖ /Users/mary/myfiles

Note: if you are using emacs on a unix non-graphical text terminal, and if 【Alt+x】 does not work, the equivalent key stroke is 【Esc x】.

Emacs will ask you with the prompt “Run find (with args): ”. If you need to do the replacement on all HTML files, then type -name "*html". If you don't care about what kind of file but simply all files under that dir, then give “-type f”.

Now, mark the files as described above.

Interactive Find/Replace

Now, you are ready to do the interactive find replace. For simplicity, let's say you just want to replace the word “quick” by “super”. Now, call dired-do-query-replace-regexp. It will prompt you for the regex string and the replacement string. Type “quick”, enter, then “super”.

Now, emacs will use your pattern and check the files, and stop and show you whenever a match occurred. When this happens, emacs will prompt you, and you have a choice of making the change or skip the change. To make the change, type y. To skip, type n. If you simply want emacs to go ahead and make all such changes to the current file, type !.

If you want to cancel the whole operation without saving any changes you've made, type 【Ctrl+g】, then exit emacs using the menu 〖File ▸ Exit Emacs〗.

Saving the Changed Files

Now, after you went through the above ordeal, there is one more step you need to do, and that is saving the changed files.

If you are using emacs version 22 or later, then call ibuffer to go into a buffer listing mode, then type 【* u】 to mark all unsaved files, then type S to save them all. (that's shift-s)

If you are using a emacs version 21, then you can do this: call list-buffers, then move the cursor to the file you want to save and type s. It will mark the file for later save action. Type u to unmark. Once you are done, type x to execute the saving of all files marked for save. (in emacs, opened file is called “buffer”. Disregard other things there.)

Alternative to the above options, you can also call save-some-buffers 【Ctrl+x s】. Then emacs will display each unsaved file and ask if you want it saved.

Note: emacs's regex is not the same as Perl or Python's, but similar. For a summary and common patterns, see: Emacs Regex.

Comment: This answer should make it more novice friendly than the most voted answer I hope. Thanks by the way for motivating me to put the whole thing instead of the link.

Comment: Answer starts with source: as the first line.
Rationale for copy pasting is: sometimes external link to blogs becomes outdated and then the answer will be rendered useless. And thus as suggested by the wiki meta. I decided to copy the whole thing.

Answer (score 5):

Using dired to recurse down a deep directory tree is going to be a bit slow for this task.  You might consider using [tags-query-replace](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags-Search.html).  This does mean shelling out to create a tags table, but that is often useful anyway, and it's quick.

Comment: Just tried on a directory with over 14,000 files. Took a few seconds to popup in Emacs. So definitely not slow (anymore).

Answer (score 3):

For open buffers, this is what I do :

```
(defun px-query-replace-in-open-buffers (arg1 arg2)
  "query-replace in all open files"
  (interactive "sRegexp:\nsReplace with:")
  (mapcar
   (lambda (x)
     (find-file x)
     (save-excursion
       (goto-char (point-min))
       (query-replace-regexp arg1 arg2)))
   (delq
    nil
    (mapcar
     (lambda (x)
       (buffer-file-name x))
     (buffer-list)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

`M-X Dired`, and t to mark all files, and `Q` to query replace text in all of them.
You can expand a sub directory by using the `i` command before the query-replace.
They key info I'm adding is that if you give a prefix (control-u) to the i command,
it will prompt you for arg, and -R argument will recursively expand all `subdirs`
into the `dired` buffer.  So now you can query-search every file in an entire directory.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [Icicles search](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview).  This is a different kind of incremental search that uses completion of your minibuffer input against search hits.  As you modify your current input the set of matching hits is updated in buffer `*Completions*`.

You can search any number of files, buffers, or bookmarked locations, which you can choose using minibuffer pattern (e.g. regexp) matching.

When you visit a search hit you can [replace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search-And-Replace) on demand either the entire hit or just the part of it that matches your current minibuffer input.  Replacement on demand means you are not queried about each search hit in turn; you access the hits you want directly, in any order.  This approach can be more effective than query-replace if you have a limited number of replacements to make: you skip the exhaustive `y/n` prompting.

Search is over search *contexts* that you define -- you are not limited to searching all of the text in the target files (e.g., you can skip comments or particular kinds of program sections).  A simple example of a search context is a line, as in `grep`, but a context can be any pattern-matched block of text you like.  Typically you define the search contexts using a regexp, but you can instead use a function. In addition to defining your own, there are predefined Icicles search commands for different kinds of contexts: blocks of text properties or overlay properties, thing-at-point things, etc.

You can also *sort* the search hits in various sort orders for easier access/navigation.

Answer (score 2):

`find-name-dired` is OK, but:

- All of the files you get match the same, single regexp.
- `find-dired` is more flexible in that regard, but it too is made for using general rules (even if they can be arbitrarily complex).  And of course `find` has its own, complex language.
- if you then want to act on only some of the files whose names were collected in the `find(-name)-dired` buffer, you need to either mark them or delete/omit the lines of those you do not want to act on.

An alternative is to use [***Dired+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/DiredPlus) commands that act on (a) the marked files and (b) all marked files (or all files, if none are marked) in the *marked subdirectories* ... found *recursively*.  This gives you both generality and easy control over file choice.  These "here-and-below" commands are all on prefix key **`M-+`** in Dired mode.

For example, **`M-+ Q`** is the same as `Q` --- query-replace, but the target files are all of those marked in the current dir and in any marked subdirs, down, down, down...

Yes, an alternative to using such here-and-below commands is to *insert* all subdirs and their subdirs, recursively, and then use a top-level command such as `Q`.  But it can often be convenient not to bother with inserted subdirs.

And to do that you anyway need a quick way to *insert all such subdirs recursively*.  Here too, **Dired+** can help.  **`M-+ M-i`** inserts all marked subdirs and their own marked subdirs, recursively.  That is, it is like `M-i` (which inserts the marked subdirs in **Dired+**), but it acts recursively on subdirs.

(All such "here-and-below" **Dired+** commands are on menu **Multiple** > **Marked Here and Below**.)

You can also perform Dired operations on an Emacs *fileset*, which is a saved set of names of files located anywhere.  And if you use [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Dired_Enhancements) then you can open a Dired buffer for just the files in a fileset or other types of saved file lists.

You can also **bookmark** any Dired buffer, including one that you create using `find(-name)-dired`.  This gives you a quick way to return to such a set (e.g. a project set) later.  And if you use [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) then bookmarking a Dired buffer records (a) its `ls` switches, (b) which files are marked, (c) which subdirectories are inserted, and (d) which (sub)directories are hidden.  All of that is restored when you "jump" to the bookmark.  **Bookmark+** also lets you bookmark an entire tree of Dired buffers --- jumping to the bookmark restores all of the buffers in the tree.

Comment: Whoever: Care to explain why you downvoted this answer?

Answer (score 2):

1. `M-x` `project-query-replace-regexp` `RET` (make sure your files are saved!).
2. `M-x` `rgrep` `RET` then `query-replace` within each buffer. Nice because you can keep track of all occurrences, and because it let's you limit search to certain extensions.

Comment: It's a shame, `project-query-replace-regexp` is not that reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest one more great tool which has not been mentioned yet, namely **[Helm](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/)**.

It is a great replacement for many standard Emacs operations involving completion, searching etc. In particular, `helm-find-files` allows for performing query replace (including regexp) within multiple selected files.

Just open `helm-find-files`, mark the relevant files with `M-SPC` and then use `F6` or `F7` to run query replace or query replace regexp in the selected files.

Comment: Can `helm-find-files` mark by regexp instead of `M-SPC`?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, no answer was given yet to make use of `-batch` Emacs mode that has been created for situations like this. So here's a simple example:

```py
$ echo foo > 1 && echo foo > 2 && echo foo > 3
$ emacs -batch --eval '(progn (dolist (file command-line-args-left) (find-file file) (replace-regexp "foo" "bar") (save-buffer) (kill-buffer)))' ./1 ./2 ./3
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
$ grep "" ./1 ./2 ./3
./1:bar
./2:bar
./3:bar
```

---

Worth noting separately that if your replacement does not fit into a small one-liner you can also save it to a file like this:

```lisp
$ cat my_replace.el
(dolist (file command-line-args-left)
  (find-file file)
  (replace-regexp "foo" "bar")
  (save-buffer)
  (kill-buffer))
$ emacs -batch -l my_replace.el ./1 ./2 ./3
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
Mark set
Replaced 1 occurrence
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not Emacs, but xxdiff comes with a tool called xx-rename which will do that for multiple strings at a time (e.g. From To from to FROM TO), with interactive prompting, save backups of all the modified files, and produce a short log of changes made with context.  That's what I tend to use when I do large/global renamings.