# How to do massive search and replace in emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs, refactoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270930/using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open)
>
> Duplicate: [using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270930/using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open)

I need to to regexp search and replace on a list of files.
Is there an emacs command (command combo) for that?
Or maybe you have a better way to do c++ refactoring on linux?

Comment: Look at Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270930/using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open).

Comment: Is there a reason why this needs to be done in emacs as opposed to another tool, such as sed?

Comment: Because everything is better when it is done in emacs.

Answer (score 3):

You can mark files in [`dired`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredMode) or [`ibuffer`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) and query-replace-regexp on them. Otherwise why not use the shell with some `find` and `sed` magic, a la:

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.cpp"); do
    mv $f $f.bak
    sed -e "s/old/new/g" $f.bak > $f
done
```

Comment: Seriously?  you can do query-replace-regexp on marked files in dired?  Good to know!

Comment: yes just mark the files you want to work on with `m` and then run query-replace-regexp using `Q`. Quite cool :)

Comment: You can also iterate over marked files in a dired buffer using dired-get-marked-files. I show an example in this blog post:

http://justinsboringpage.blogspot.com/2009/04/running-elisp-function-on-each-marked.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [XRefactory](http://www.xref.sk/xrefactory/main.html)?

Comment: so YOU HAVE looked into it, eh?