# I want to search a directory and replace all occurrences of a word in emacs

Tags: emacs, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270930/using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open)

I am using emacs and want to replace a word (well, all functions called foo() to foobar()) for all occurrences in a directory of source files. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burton's answer is as easy as it gets. Here's one way to do it in Emacs:

`M-x dired` fill in the directory you want to work in

`* s` marks all files in the directory

`Q` runs query-replace-regex on all marked files. Fill in the search regex and the replace string.

Type `!` to replace all occurrences in each file. You will have to go back to save the changes though.

Comment: You can also get a dired buffer of a directory by just opening it with `find-file`, too.  `M-x find-dired` if you want to include files in subdirectories as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the shell:

```
sed -i 's/foo\(/foobar\(/g' *.c *.h
```

this will replace all instances of foo( with foobar(.