# In Emacs, how can we go to another file already found by the previous dired-find-name / findr.el?

Tags: emacs

This is in accordance to question [Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270930/using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open). I already tried using find-name-dired and also package findr.el. It did open a file where the matching text found, but... how can I go to another file, not this automatically opened file????

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like more than one question.

`find-name-dired` will create a results buffer listing all the files with matching filenames. Use <kbd>C-h m</kbd> to see dired-mode's  help, and all its key-bindings. <kbd>RET</kbd> will open the file at point, <kbd>o</kbd> will open the file at point in another window, and <kbd>C-o</kbd> will do the same, but leaves you in the *Find* window (which is convenient if you want to quickly visit several of those files).

`findr-search` (which is what it sounds like you're using) appears to work more like a tags mechanism. <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `findr-search` <kbd>RET</kbd> says that you can navigate to the next match with <kbd>M-,</kbd>. This will cycle through the matches in the current file, and then on to the next file as necessary.

Comment: Yes! Yes! What I need is M-, That's soo helpful! I use package findr.el from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindrPackage and I can go to subsequent match using M-, Thanks you so much phils!

Comment: excuse me, but how can I go back to the previous match? that is the reverse of M-,? thanks :)

Comment: It looks like findr sets the mark for each match you move to, so you could cycle backwards through the local marks set in the current buffer with `C-u C-SPC`, and you can cycle back through the global mark ring with `C-x C-SPC` to get to each previous file in turn (whereupon you can again use `C-u C-SPC` to visit that buffer's local marks).

Comment: Note that if you're using cua-mode or cua-selection-mode, then after an initial `C-u C-SPC` you can repeat the pop-to-mark as many times as required by typing just `C-SPC`. I often find this quite convenient. See `cua-set-mark` for details.

Comment: Funny is, I haven't use emacs for a while, and I want to know exactly the thing in this question. I was helped by my own question ;) Thanks @phils