# Add text to the top of multiple files in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'd like to add a couple lines of text (copyright) to the top of all text files in a directory. Can I do this in emacs without copy/pasting for each file?

Answer (score 3):

This is copied from Chris Conway's answer to a different question: [Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270930/using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open)

1. M-x find-name-dired: you will be prompted for a root directory and a filename pattern.
2. Press t to "toggle mark" for all files found.
3. Press Q for "Query-Replace in Files...": you will be prompted for query/substitution regexps.
4. Proceed as with query-replace-regexp: SPACE to replace and move to next match, n to skip a match, etc.

You can use it the same way

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with

```
find . -type f -exec emacs -batch '{}' --eval '(insert-string "foo\nbar\nbaz\n")' -f save-buffer \;
```

or something to that effect. The emacs bit is

```
emacs -batch filename --eval '(insert-string "foo\nbar\nbaz\n")' -f save-buffer
```

replace `"foo\nbar\nbaz"` with your message. However, using emacs for this is really a lot of overkill. You could just put your copyright header into a file and use `cat header file > tempfile; mv tempfile file`.