# Emacs dabbrev-expand for whole line

Tags: emacs, completion

Is there some possibility to achieve whole line completion in emacs?
I mean something similar to vim's `C-x C-l` - like `dabbrev-expand` but completing whole line.

Comment: Questions about *using* programs such as Emacs are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they are specific to programming modes; you may be able to get help on [emacs.se] or [su].  If your question is about programming Emacs, then please [edit] to include a [mcve] of the Lisp or C code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your objections. I see plenty of questions about **using** emacs, like for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270930/using-emacs-to-recursively-find-and-replace-in-text-files-not-already-open

It also includes example: I am looking for something similar to the functionality vim has (^X^L)

Comment: @TobySpeight: Huh? Since when? Not so - at all, AFAIK.

Comment: @Lemurata: yeah, that one looks off-topic as well; it ought to be flagged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, look at `hippie-exp`, which is part of base emacs. Specifically, add `try-expand-line` to `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`. Personally, I use a modification similar to [this one](https://gist.github.com/magnars/4060654) that completes on closest matching prefix first.

Comment: Thats it! :) Thanks a lot!