# Forcing myself to master Emacs

Tags: macos, emacs

Assuming a superficial knowledge exists, how might one go about forcing a mastery of Emacs?

Assume also that said person currently uses [Aquamacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquamacs) but falls back on Mac OS X-isms far too often.  This person is serious (this time for sure), and needs some advice.

Comment: I have a similar problem - not on mac os x but with mastering emacs.  I couldn't get tabs to work the way I wanted them to last time around.

Comment: why? If you have Aquamacs and like it, why switch?

Comment: Because I might not always have Aquamacs.

Comment: With awk, mono developer, eclipse, gnome developer, gnu editor, abi, is there a reason for me to go beyond vi unless i wish to collect another editor trophy or prove to my technologically monastic self that I should abandon the world and deprive myself to choose to do the penance of emacs?

Comment: don't forget to visit #emacs @ freenode :)

Comment: @h2g2java I find emacs extremely useful and easy to use once you get used to its way of naming things and find your way around the help system. I also enjoy it. Don't learn it if it feels like a pointless chore to prove something, but try and learn it and keep going while you're still having fun.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>

Take the tutorial, and actually follow it all the way through.

Then, learn some of the more useful time-saving functionality, like <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> to start recording a macro, <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd> to finish, and <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> to execute the last macro. Read the manual (<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>emacs</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>) for more details. Try learning to browse through the documentation within `info` mode in Emacs, rather than resorting to the web, to get more used to how navigation works in Emacs.

Oh, and try using an Emacs that doesn't have the Aquamacs key bindings. There is a command line version of Emacs included on Mac OS X, though using the Meta key is a pain there (you have to either set your Terminal preferences to use <kbd>Option</kbd> as meta, or always use <kbd>Esc</kbd>). You can also use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to install an X11 version of Emacs, which won't have the Mac style keybindings.

Also, try using Emacs keybindings in other Cocoa text editing views. It's not something that a lot of people know, but a few common Emacs keybindings also work in the standard Cocoa text controls, such as <kbd>C-a</kbd> to go to the beginning of a line, <kbd>C-e</kbd> to go to the end, <kbd>C-k</kbd> to kill to the end of the line, <kbd>C-y</kbd> to yank from the kill buffer (which is different than the pasteboard). <kbd>C-t</kbd> transposes two characters, and I'm sure there are more that I can't think of at the moment. Using these on a regular basis will get your fingers used to Emacs keybindings (many of these also generally work in most shells, and in programs that use GNU Readline for being able to accept editable input).

For any technology you use on a regular basis, seek out the best Emacs mode you can for that technology, and learn it inside and out. For instance, if you're a Git user, I find [Magit](http://zagadka.vm.bytemark.co.uk/magit/) indispensable. If you program JavaScript, make sure you use Steve Yegge's [js2-mode](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/js2-mode-new-javascript-mode-for-emacs.html). If you use Common Lisp, learn [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), if you use Erlang learn [distel](http://code.google.com/p/distel/). Sometimes, the best Emacs mode won't be the best tool you can find for a job, but for many, many things it's pretty good, and great to have it all integrated in to the same editor and environment.

Keep practicing everything you learn, over and over. I find that I frequently learn a new Emacs keybinding, and then promptly forget it because I don't use it for another 6 months. You can alleviate this problem by looking for any excuse you can to use a new keybinding after you first learn it, to help get it ingrained in your memory.

Comment: FYI js2-mode is deprecated in favor of espresso. See http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2009-08/msg00395.html and particularly Steve Yegge's comments at http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2009-08/msg00619.html

Comment: I use [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) to run emacs on a Mac, that's quite handy since I can use the meta key. To run MY emacs with 'nw,' and not the default I use `alias emacs='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw'` and have the newest [GNU Emacs For Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/)  in my /Applications folder.

Answer (score 10):

- Don't use Mail.app, Gmail, or whatever -- use Gnus.
- Don't use a web browser for programming information, use Info pages
  where possible.
- Don't use Terminal, use M-x shell.
- Make sure you have a right and a left control key. I have a MacBook and have mapped the right option key to control.
- Swap left control and capslock.
- Read [Steve Yegge's](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/effective-emacs) advice.
- [Find a killer app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269812/how-to-quickly-get-started-at-using-and-learning-emacs/270615#270615).
- Always, always, always read the Emacs manual and use M-x apropos when you want to do something but don't quite know how. Emacs probably has the best online help of any program, ever.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is good advice (though it's a bit farther than I would go; I don't use Gnus, for instance, and I find that M-x shell isn't as good as Terminal). Some people may not know how to swap caps-lock and control; it's actually pretty simple, you can just go into System Preferences, go to Keyboard, and click Modifier Keys, to remap your modifiers. I actually just have both keys mapped to control, since I almost never need caps-lock and it makes it less confusing for other people who need to use my keyboard.

Comment: I don't use Gnus anymore either (if my work e-mail supported IMAP/SMTP/POP, I would.) But it really got me to learn the text editing features quickly. :)

Comment: How do you map right option as control outside of a terminal?

Comment: There's a program called DoubleCommand that did this when I wrote the comment: http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This answer is great, but I've found eshell to be superior to shell, Did you have a specific reason for recommending shell over eshell @StevenHuwig?

Comment: @bneil Only that it was for interacting with standard shell built-ins  rather than emacs-specific variants. Eshell is certainly a better user experience, particularly on Windows without cygwin.

Answer (score 6):

I found the only way to master anything is to do it daily (practice, practice, practice).

As far as Mac OS X-isms... I'm not sure that's a problem per-say. Personally, in my quest to master [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), I ditched Mac OS X entirely and have been happily living in GNU/Linux-land since.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Practice.

Try to answer questions here that are tagged Emacs.

Practice more.

Visit the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/) and try ideas from it.

Practice even more.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Notice you are doing something complicated.

Step 2: Read the manual to see if there's an easier way.

Step 3: Undo your changes.

Step 4: Do things the "new way".

Step 5: You've just learned one more new feature.  Go to Step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to [Carbon Emacs](http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html) which doesn't have all the Mac bindings. It's a lot closer to the Unix Emacs experience but doesn't require X11 installed. The only real downside to Carbon Emacs is that Apple has no 64 bit Carbon and is probably phasing Carbon out, so Carbon Emacs might not have a long life ahead of it.

Comment: Or just use the text mode GNU emacs already available on mac os!